# Request with Symfony HttpClient returns code 0, when the same request with postman works fine

Tags: docker, symfony, mercure, symfony-http-client

I have a weird problem where a request I make (to my mercure hub) with postman works fine, however the Publisher class (from the Symfony mercure bundle), which uses the Symfony HttpClient will yield in a response code 0. 
According to my research that means that the URL can't be found, or no Response was returned?

I first thought it might have to do something with the Publisher class itself, which is why opened this [Issue on Github](https://github.com/symfony/mercure/issues/19), but after some playing around I thought that maybe there is a communication error with my containers? I tried giving my mercure container "networks: internal", which some other containers use aswell, but that didn't help either.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated..

/e: my docker-compose:

```
version: "3"

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v1.7
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./.docker/traefik/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
    networks:
      - proxy
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.docker.network=proxy
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.heracles.local
      - traefik.port=8080

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.17-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./Source:/var/www
      - ./.docker/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    links:
      - php
    networks:
      - internal
      - proxy
    labels:
      - traefik.docker.network=proxy
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.basic.frontend.rule=Host:heracles.local
      - traefik.basic.port=80

  php:
    build:
      args:
        USER_ID: ${USER_ID}
      context: ./.docker/php
    volumes:
      - ./Source:/var/www
      - ./.docker/php/conf/cli.ini:/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/zz-symfony.ini
      - ./.docker/php/conf/fpm.ini:/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/zz-symfony.ini
      - ./.docker/php/conf/xdebug.ini:/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/zz-xdebug.ini
      - ./.docker/php/conf/opcache.ini:/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/zz-opcache.ini
      - ./.docker/php/conf/pool.conf:/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
    networks:
      - internal
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=false

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./.docker/mysql/conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d
    command:
      - --character-set-server=utf8mb4
      - --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
      - --skip-character-set-client-handshake
    networks:
      - internal
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=false
    restart: always

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    networks:
      - internal
      - proxy
    labels:
      - traefik.docker.network=proxy
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.basic.frontend.rule=Host:db.heracles.local
      - traefik.basic.port=8080

  blackfire:
    image: blackfire/blackfire
    networks:
      - internal
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=false

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    networks:
      - internal
      - proxy
    labels:
      - traefik.docker.network=proxy
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.basic.frontend.rule=Host:mail.heracles.local
      - traefik.basic.port=8025

  mercure:
    image: dunglas/mercure
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS=1
      - CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=*
      - JWT_KEY=ASD
      - PUBLISH_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=http://heracles.local
      - ADDR=:3000
    ports:
      - 3000:3000

networks:
  internal:
  proxy:
    external: true

volumes:
  db_data:
```

Comment: If you're using docker-compose, can you share it ?

Comment: @AliBenZarrouk I can share it tonight when I am home. A colleague just told me that I might have to change my MERCURE_PUBLISH_URL=http://heracles.local:3000/.well-known/mercure to merucre:3000/.well-known/...., because my mercure container is called "mercure". I'll try it tonight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright guys it's working now. In fact the correct url is 
MERCURE_PUBLISH_URL=http://mercure:3000/.well-known/mercure
So if you're using Docker Containers make sure to pass the correct host + the port and give your mercure containers the network of your other containers (internal in my case).

Answer (score 1):

In reference to your comment, your `MERCURE_PUBLISH_URL` .env variable must indeed refer to your Mercure container, but there's no need for the port indication. If the name of your Mercure container is "mercure", the environment variable should be set like so :

`MERCURE_PUBLISH_URL=http://mercure/.well-known/mercure`

(Replace `http` by `https` if your connection is secured)

Comment: Right now I get the error "Couldn't connect to server for "http://mercure/.well-known/mercure"." 

 $httpClient = HttpClient::create();
            $response = $httpClient->request('POST', 'http://mercure/.well-known/mercure', [
  "auth_bearer" => "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJtZXJjdXJlIjp7InB1Ymxpc2giOlsiaHR0cDovL2hlcmFjbGVzLmxvY2FsIl19fQ.3DiIS7-ktVyQtVrJTvFwmkBD8IweYNVL--tef-UWqPo",
  "body" => "topic=http%3A%2F%2Fheracles.local%2Flive%2Fchat%2Fget%2F1&data=%7B%22newMessage%22%3A%22asdasd%22%2C%22author%22%3A%22mehlichmeyer%22%7D"
]);

Comment: @mehlichmeyer Did you try to put `heracles.local:3000/.well-known/mercure` for your post request url? Because on the project I have with Mercure, I don't mention the port in the .env variable and it works fine (and when I subscribe to the hub in my template I subscribe to `http://localhost:3000/.well-known/mercure`).  
But maybe it's because I'm using the Publisher/Update entities of the Mercure bundle. Do you have any particular reason to use the HttpClient instead?

Comment: I am actually using the Publisher aswell, but the Publisher itself has the dependency on the HttpClient. I tried with heracles.local/localhost and it wouldn't work, are you using Docker Containers aswell? For my comment from yesterday I just injected the HttpClient to my controller to try things out, but now that the host can be found the Publisher works just fine and I am using that instead :)

Comment: Ok, too bad that it doesn't work with your local url. I'm using Docker container as well! And I really just need to put http://mercure/.well-known/mercure for MERCURE_PUBLISH_URL, without the port  But that doesn't matter, glad it works on your side now :)